# JavaScript, Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generate combinations (I'll explain below), and I used a recursive function.

I got this error `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

I know the error because I call the recursive function a lot of times.

how I can solve the problem. here is the code

```
const chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

generate = (maxChar: number) => {
    const generatePossibleCombinations = (starterChar = "") => {
        const result = [];

        if (starterChar.length == maxChar) return [starterChar];

        for (let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            result.push.apply(result, generatePossibleCombinations(starterChar + chars[i]));
        }

        return result;
    };

    return generatePossibleCombinations();
};


console.log(generate(3));
// output "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "AG" -> etc
```

but if I call

```
console.log(generate(5));
// Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan No, the recursion base case is fine: `if (starterChar.length == maxChar)` works. (Sure, to be safer one might try `if (starterChar.length >= maxChar)` but it works either way.)

Comment: The problem is the `push.apply(…)`. Passing **a lot** arguments to `push` will exceed the stack size. Copy them over one by one, or use a different method, or even better (more performant, not necessarily cleaner) accumulate your results in an outer-scope array instead of `return`ing them.

Comment: @Bergi wups. Correct

Comment: @Bergi yes its the same

Comment: @Bergi i don't know exactly what alternative I should use!